# Is there a way to further shorten and generalize this Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I currently have the following Makefile

```
test:  main.o car.o student.o   house.o 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o test main.o car.o student.o house.o
    objcopy --only-keep-debug test test.debug   

main.o: student.h house.h    main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp

car.o: car.h
student.o: student.h car.h
house.o: house.h
```

My question is can I shorten the file as to something like

```
test:   *.o 
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o test *.o
        objcopy --only-keep-debug test test.debug
```

How would the target dependency work? The reason I am thinking about pursuing something like this is because I would not like to add stuff to my Makefile everytime I add a new header or cpp file?

Comment: What do you think is `*.o` ?

Comment: *.o would be all the object files

Comment: All which object files?

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you want, with automatic dependency recomputation:

```
CPPFLAGS += -MMD
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.C *.c *.cpp *.cxx *.c++)
OBJECTS = $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SOURCES)))
.PHONY: all
all: appname appname.debug
appname.debug: appname
    objcopy --only-keep-debug $< $@
appname: $(OBJECTS)
include *.d
```

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options for the `-MMD`-option, which on compilation extracts dependencies to `.d`-files

I computed all possible source-files and from them all object-files, because **`*.o` would only match already existing files**.

Comment: This looks very interesting. I am going to look into this and post back. Thanks for the post

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can use `test:   *.o` in a makefile.

You likely don't want to though. That will never include `.o` files for newly created `.c` files as they will not exist.

You can do away with listing each file in the recipe body though by using the `$^` [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

Answer (score 0):

It is a *good* idea to "add stuff to Makefile everytime I add a cpp file", and you should convince yourself to it.

The first reason is, if you change the Makefile everytime you change source list, and you depend the targets on the Makefile, then the targets will automatically recompile when you change the source list, as they should, and that is the way Make was designed to work.  Don't fight it.

The second reason  is, you want to declare your sources explicitly somewhere, so you can clarify your intentions to yourself and others.  My practice shows this makes code more maintainable.

The third reason is, so you can add other files, perhaps temporary, with the same extensions, which are not sources.

Bearing that in mind, here I think is the best way to rewrite your Makefile.  Note that I did not do any  automatic dependency generation here.  If you do that, then instead of listing various dependencies of `.o` files on `.h` files, you would have them generated automatically, as others pointed out.

```
SRCS := main.cpp car.cpp student.cpp house.cpp

OBJS := $(SRCS:cpp=o)

.PHONY: all
all: test test.debug

test:  $(OBJS) Makefile 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)

%.debug: % Makefile
    objcopy --only-keep-debug $< $@  

$(OBJS): %o: %cpp Makefile
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< 

main.o: student.h house.h

car.o: car.h

student.o: student.h car.h

house.o: house.h
```

Comment: Could you explain a little about the changes that you suggested. This would definitely help everyone out a lot

Comment: You know, DRY is a tenet of software-design for a reason: Any repetition makes subtle differences possible and thus more likely (Which means bugs). Especially if there is nothing checking the various places you lay down the same information against each other.